# How to connect multiple namespaces with a same namespace linux

Tags: linux, namespaces

I tried to connect multiple namespaces with another namespace that reacts like a vpn.

I tried this solution - [how-to-forward-traffic-between-linux-network-namespaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391193/how-to-forward-traffic-between-linux-network-namespaces)

Basically using “ip link add name vethhost0 type veth peer name vethvpn0” to connect the namespaces, but when I want to connect multiple vethhost0/1/2/3 to vethvpn0.

I tired also adding pairs to the same namespace (vpn) with vethvpn1.. and it just blocked all communication except the first one (vethhost0).

Any idea?